# Evaluating limit of a function, given an inequality

Tags: limits

> Given that $9x−41 \leq f(x) \leq x^2+x−25$, determine $\lim\limits_{x\to4}f(x)$.
>   What theorem did you use to arrive at your answer?

I tried to do it this several times!

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
$$\begin{align*}&\lim_{x \to 4}\left[9x - 41\right] = -5\\
&\lim_{x \to 4} \left[x^2 + x - 25 \right]= -5.
\end{align*}$$

Now apply the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).